# Focal function in R

Tags: r, raster

I want to run focal values for neighbourhood of focal cells using a matrix, with a function preferably. My data has 0, 1, and 2 as values, and I want to add values of "1" only, if I am using the focal function.

It's probably a very simple question, and I have tried many combinations, but still not getting the desired results.

Please help!

Here's one of the codes that I was attempting:

```
# to generate the function

  my.function <- function (x) {
    ux <- unique(x)
    ux [if (x==1) ux <- focal(in_image, w=matrix(1/9, ncol=3, nrow=3)), fun=sum]
    }

# to run the focal window for the desired function

  r_new <- focal(in_image, w=matrix(1/9, ncol=3, nrow=3), fun=my.function)
```

Comment: You want to apply a sum to a 3x3 window when the raster cell = 1?

Comment: Yes, but I've figured it out (in the comments below). Thanks though!

Answer (score 2):

You are calling focal in your function. The function is passed to focal and should represent what you want done in the local window. I have no idea what the application of unique() is accomplishing. In your case and conditional sum would simply be:

```
r_new <- focal(in_image, w=matrix(1/9, ncol=3, nrow=3), fun=function(x) sum(x[x==1]))
```

Comment: I tried this function but I keep getting 0 in the resulting output, and NA in the boundary cells.

Comment: Are you using the "na.rm=TRUE" argument?

Comment: No, I wasn't using that argument. I made slight changes and managed to get the desired results. Thanks for your help! Here's the final code:
`r_new <- focal(in_image,w=matrix(1, ncol=3, nrow=3), fun=function(x) sum(x[x==1]))`